# why it doesn't output the product from the if loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, helper

Everything works but it doesn't produce the workout and keep asking me to input the skill from the list. I want to ask the user to input the skill, output the workout and keep asking them to put another skill. Otherwise input stop to break out the loop.

```
skill4 = ['defense', 'finishing', 'athleticism', 'posting']

print('Focus on: \nDefense \nPosting \nAthleticism \nFinishing')

skill4 = str.lower(input('Select 1 skill you want to improve on the list: '))

while True:

   if work != skill4:

       skill4 = str.lower(input('Please select 1 skill from above: '))

   if work == skill4[0]:

       print (' \nYour exercises are: ')

       print('Lateral training 40 seconds \nShuffle on a line 40 seconds \nladder training: 40 seconds')

       if work == skill4[1]:

           print (' \nYour exercises are: ')

           print('Side hook: 10 makes (per side)\nScoop: 10 makes (per side)\nFloater: 10 makes (per side)')

           if work == skill4[2]:

               print (' \nYour exercises are: ')

               print('Run 7 miles per hour for 30 minutes (break each 15)\nJump squat: 40 seconds\nRope skipping: 1 min 30 sec')

               if work == skill4[3]:

                   print (' \nYour exercises are: ')

                   print('Up and under move (15 times)\nKobe fadeaway move (15 times)\nCut to short corner, receive pass from wing and shoot. (10 times) ')

                   if work == "stop":

                       break

                   else: skill4 = str.lower(input('Select another skill: '))
```

Comment: There is an indentation problem in your code, the `if` should be on the same level, and you should probably use `elif`after the second `if`

Comment: It seems `work` is never set. Maybe you meant to in place of `skill4` again?

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
skill4 = str.lower(input('Select 1 skill you want to improve on the list: '))
```

you are setting the variable skill4, thus overwriting your list of skills. Because the *work* variable stays undefined, you will not be able to compare it later.

You also have an indentation problem. The if statements are nested. Because of that, you only check if work == skill4[1] when work == skill4[0], which can never be true.

The last problem I see is not very noticable but very annoying: in this line

```
if work != skill4:
```

You check if the item selected is a valid work item, but you compare it to the list instead of checking if it is in the list. You would do that this way:

```
if work not in skill4:
```

I hope this helps you!